# Sharing Table for Activities

Tags: sharing, activities

When I try to query the sharing table for task it tells me that taskShare is not supported. Is there any way to access the sharing table for tasks or events?

```
Select id, RowCause, UserOrGroupId from taskShare
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Master detail relationship detail objects sharing is controlled by parent. You have to query on tasks ParentObjectShare object to get sharing table of task.

E.g you want to query sharing information of tasks related to Case.

```
Select RowCause, UserOrGroupId,  from CaseShare WHERE CaseId = : taskObj.WhatId
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What would that look like syntactically?